# Debug a web service linked with an application on XP machine

Tags: c#, web-services, debugging

I'm new to web services and I'm stuck with a problem.
I have code for a client application and code for a web service both of them written on C# 
The client application is using this web service to call a procedure
I have created an IIS(5.1) virtual directory on my machine and I want to go through the client application into the web service debugging to see the web service procedure how is working.
I have XP as O.S. and use visual studio 2003.
Thanks

Flo

Comment: Wow, 2003?  On XP?  With IIS 5.1?  The frist step is to upgrade to Windows 7 and VS 2010.  Then perhaps you will find that you can run the remote debugger application found on the install CD for VS.

Comment: well, I don't have windows 7 or VS 2010 company policy:))

Comment: You should tell Progressive Insurance to get a new policy Flo.  Hahahaha.

Answer (score 1):

you can open the webservice solution in VS 2003 and follow debug => attach to process and attach aspnet_wp.exe or w3wp.exe.
If you want to debug through your client application, both your client application and webservice should be opened in the same VS 2003 instance, and you should attach both your client application and aspnet_wp.exe

Comment: Thanks well I tried I opened one instance of VS2003 on client and other instance on web service, I was able to attach aspnet_wp.exe on web service and I tried run the client but it won't go into the web service

Comment: Did you use a version of the service built with debug turned on and output debug symbols?  Basically did you use the Release version or a debug build?

Comment: Hi I used the debug build, I have opened in the same instance client and added the web service project, I attached the aspnet_wp.exe but still no chance Flo